# c# webforms testing strategy

Tags: c#, testing, webforms

I wondered if anyone had links or comments on strategy as regards to testing a webforms application, I am referring specifically to automated testing practices, and unit testing.

My current strategy has been to separate business logic into a separate DLL that can be Unit tested on a class by class basis. However when it comes to testing the web Forms themselves using code UI tests, it appears I should be running two instances of visual studio 2010, one for the application and the other in order to run the created UI tests.

I found this link:
  [Testing ASP.NET webforms applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301659/testing-asp-net-webforms-applications)
However while this link was interesting it does not answer my question with regard to a strategy on a green fields project.

Although MVC3 would solve some of this, part of my reason for sticking with webforms is that I am slowly migrating aspects of a legacy system and to start from scratch on everything, when I can migrate strategic parts does not make sense.

Any links comments or observations would be welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 You can try with Selenium if you want just test your interfaces

http://seleniumhq.org/

2 On functionnal subject (Code behind) It's very difficult to test because you must mock your pipeline, when i compare to MVC.

So for example you can mock HttpContextBase

```
var mock = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
```

Comment: VS 2010 provides the coded UI tests which allows testing of the UI, I have therefore elected to stick to MS in order to keep my testing under one roof namely MS.

Comment: i speak also about mock and context